# How can I use XMLHttpRequest() to constantly send data to another page in my website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working in node.js and express.js and am trying to find the FASTEST way I can deal with this problem.

One page in my website is receiving location information in latitude `var lat` and longitude `var long`, and I want to constantly be sending that information to another page on my website. My code is very incomplete but any guidance is extremely helpful. I'm currently getting the error `http://localhost/driver/save_position Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and later `POST http://localhost/driver/save_position net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in the browser console. My code is below.

This is code in a javascript file run on one webpage that I want to send the information to my other page so that it can constantly update.

```
function sendCoordinates(lat, lon){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("POST", "http://" + window.location.hostname + "/driver/save_position", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send('lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon);
}
```

In a separate file for my routing I have

```
router.post('/driver/save_position',function(req, res, next){
  console.log(req)
})
```

I'm very much a beginner with all of these kinds of ideas so any advice, help, and solutions are extremely appreciated! Thank you for any help!

Comment: Does your express console show your XHR request hitting the URL?

Comment: "I want to constantly be sending that information to another page on my website." Can you please clarify what you mean here?

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen I have one page where the latitude and longitude will be inputted by a driver and then I'm trying to send that information to another page of my website where its placed on a map for another user somewhere else in the world to see where that driver is.

Comment: @char No nothing comes up on my express console when that page is run, only errors on the browser console

Comment: Will the other user see the lat, long data immediately? i.e., will the other user be shown the lat-long position of the driver as soon as the driver uploads his position?

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen - Yes that is the goal. I have the driver's position coming in every 5 seconds so I would want the user to get that location every 5 seconds as well. If there is a small delay for some reason though that would be okay.

Answer (score 2):

One web page does not send data directly to another web page unless it's in the same browser.  So since you're saying "another page on your website", I assume you're talking about making data appear in some other page for some other user.  If that's what you mean, then that just isn't a capability that browser Javascript has.  Also, it's not really clear what you mean when you say "send to a web page" as that isn't really a destination.

What you can do is to send a request to a server and you can ask that server to notify some other connected user/page.  If that other user/page has a live webSocket connect to the server, then server can send a message to that user/page over the webSocket.

If the other user/page does not have a live webSocket connection to the same server, then the only way it can get this information from the server is for it to request that information from the server with its own Ajax call.  The server would have to store that information so when someone asks for it, it could supply the info.

---

If you are asking how to send data from one window in the browser to another window in the same browser, then you can use `postMessage()` to send data between two coooperating windows in the same browser.

Comment: _"One web page does not send data directly to another web page. That just isn't a capability that browser Javascript has"_ `SharedWorker()` can communicate between tabs, browsing contexts. Possibly also `postMessage()`, `MessageChannel()`, depending on how OP is defining "another page".

Comment: @guest271314 - I've updated my answer to address both cases - either sending data to another user or sending data to another window in the same browser.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Yes, I'm sorry for the poor wording - here's a clarification - I'm trying to take the coordinates of a "driver" (where the driver goes to one webpage and clicks a button "track me") and have the "driver"'s location appear on another page for a another user. So how would I send a request to the server to hold this information and could I have a function within my page for the other user that loops an Ajax call to retrieve most recent coordinates of the "driver"?

Comment: @jfriend00 is this possible and relatively easy to do?

Comment: @namore - I can't really tell what specifically you're asking.  You can certainly set up your own web server, set up some request handlers on it to handle incoming requests, then create a client that will regular send requests to the web server, either sending data, requesting data or both.  That's basic client/server development - how the web works.  I'm not sure what you're asking here beyond that.